# AtomでHydrogenを用いてRをコンパイルする場合に日本語がでない

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor

AtomエディタでHydrogenパッケージ、jupyter、IRkernelを用いてRを動かそうとしており、
以下のサイトなどを参考に構築をしました。
https://nussilovesdata.eu/post/setting-up-atom-for-r/
https://gomiba.co.in/blog/archives/831

しかし、Atom上でRの日本語を含むコードを実行しようとすると、
下の画像のように、<U+XXXX>のようなユニコード(?)で表示されてしまいます。
ちなみに、同様にPythonを実行する場合は、問題なく日本語が表示されます。
当方プログラミングやencodingに慣れておらず、何が原因なのか検討がつきません。

どなたか、原因や解決策をご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

[image: Rを実行した場合]

[image: Pythonを実行した場合]

Comment: Rにて Sys.getlocale()  の結果を貼ってみて頂けますか？